# swiper setWrapperTranslate can not work when moving

Tags: swiper.js

I am use swiper to achieve pull up to load next page on mobile using `html5`,and my page have a refresh button,when clicked it,it should load fisrt page data and the page should Recovery my first enter the page.

Now,the problem is: when I push up and load next page, I clicked the refresh button and invoke `setWrapperTranslate(0)`,but it doesn't work, how to change wrapper translate when the slides is moving?